# Is it better to pass data via intent or query the database when needed?

Tags: android, sql, database, android-intent

I am just wondering what would be the better way to handle data in several activities in android.

Say I had two activities, A and B, that hold some views. First I load some data from a SQL database and inflate the views in A. Now, I want to start activity B, which uses the same set of data as A did.

Is it better to pass the data via Intent (`putExtra()`) and then inflate the views or is it better to query the database again and then inflate.

I am not sure about that, because both approaches seem to have their disadvantages:

- Querying the database takes more time /more resources
- Putting extra data to the intent makes it more complex, because of putting and getting the data (especially when working with more activities)

Can someone give me some advice on what is the best practice?

Comment: use application class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As compare to DB Query use Intent.

And another way is, use one common class which will holds your data temporary.

Answer (score 0):

There is various way to pass and get data. It is more useful to use Intent than DB query.

But there is another useful way is shared prefernce. Through which you can create,edit, delete data as well as can fetch data from any of the activity.

**To create or edit shared preference:**

```
String share_pref_file = "your_file_name";      
SharedPreferences prefs1 = getSharedPreferences(
        share_pref_time_file, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = prefs1.edit();
editor1.putString("your_data", data); //data is your variable
editor1.commit();
```

**To fetch data:**

```
String share_pref_file = "your_file_name";
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(share_pref_file,
    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String strJson = prefs.getString("your_data", "");
```

**To delete:**

```
String share_pref_file = "your_file_name";
SharedPreferences prefs1 = getSharedPreferences(
            share_pref_file, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs1.edit();
    editor.remove(share_pref_file);
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
```

Comment: Shared preference is fine when you have less number of data and it will only used when you need to use that data through out to app and oftenly used. It is not better way because Shared preference data will be stored in Device RAM, so app will work slow and may be it would crashed because of Memory issues.